# If $\lfloor x^i\rfloor =i,i=1,2,3,\cdots,n$ find the maximum of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the maximum $n$ for which there exist a real number $x$ such that
>   $$\lfloor x^i\rfloor =i,\quad i=1,2,3,\ldots,n.$$

$\lfloor x\rfloor =1$,then $1<x<2$,

$\lfloor x^2\rfloor =2$ then $\sqrt{2}<x<\sqrt{3}$.
so How to find the maximum of $n?$

Comment: You tried what happens for $n=1,2$. Did you try it for larger values of $n$?

Comment: Yes，I have tried it,so I found $n\le 10$? But I can't find the maximum

Comment: We must have $x \ge \sqrt[3]3$, but also $x^i < i+1$ for $i=4,5,\ldots,n$. Check each value of $i$ in this range to see if $(\sqrt[3]3)^i < i+1$.

Comment: How to prove contradiction for $n=5?$

Comment: @Australia:Just put my comment and mhp's comment together.

Comment: Just use a spreadsheet program and calculate the range for x if ⌊xi⌋=i, for i = 1, 2, 3, ... 20 and then it should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(\root3\of3)^5>6.{}$